# Is there a convention for naming a collection with 1-to-1 relationship?

Tags: java, javascript, naming-conventions, conventions

Let's say we have:

```
var playerNames = ["Michael Jordan", "Scottie Pippen", "Tony Kukoc"]
```

How is to call that variable?

1. playerNames
2. playersNames
3. namesOfPlayers
4. nameOfPlayers

P.S. We are in the situation here where classes/structures are not possible.

Comment: I'd say go with `playerNames`.

Comment: choose any convention according to your comfort but be stick to that throughout the application.btw playerNames is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Identifiers should be easy to read and understand, and therefor they should usually be short and consist of as few words as possible. Moreover, they should be easy to distinguish.

For this reason, all the names with the `Of` are not suitable, because they contain an unnecessary word.

By widely used convention, a posession-relation between words (the names are owned by players) is not included in identifiers, so `playersNames` (with the s at the end of `player`) is usually not preferred.

What remains is `playerNames`, which is already a good choice, or a name ending in `...List`.

When you have a list of player names, then it is likely that you also have a variable in your code for a signle player's name. You most likely call this one `playerName`. Now, for distinguishing this from `playerNames`, you have only the plural `s` at the end, which is a very small difference for the human eye. Some programmers therefor prefer to call the arrays or lists `playerNameList`. Then it's easy to distinguish it from `playerName`.

Which of the two you prefer, `playerNames` or `playerNameList`, is up to you. Both conventions are widely used. I personally prefer the `...List` variant.

Answer (score 1):

I would say playerNames makes most sense. Then you could have more data like

```
var playerAges = [51, 48, 45];
```

and it would look neat with everything pertaining to players, prepended with "player".

I usually use: what is this data type? It's a playerName. Are there lots of them? Yes, so it's playerNames. Also when you iterate over them you can do

```
for(var i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++)
{
    var playerName = playerNames[i];
    // ... do stuff
}
```

I don't believe it really matters what naming convention you use as long as it is consistent throughout your application and makes sense to you, and perhaps others who would come to read your code later on.

Answer (score 0):

All the mentioned names follow the variable name convention. just use any which conveys the usage to you and your team.(you can do a vote out too :))

In your case the objective can be achieved by using `players` alone.